# Milliseconds format php

Tags: php, date-format

I got this number: **116041** (is it in milliseconds).

And i want to transform to something like this **minuts:seconds:miliseconds**

Theoretically that number should transform to something like: **1:56:xx**

And I'm trying this code:

```
$diff = 116041;
$date = date("i:s:u",$diff);
echo $date;
```

But I'm getting this output:

> 14:01:000000

Comment: Have you tried *math*? Hint: the correct answer is `1:56.041`.

Answer (score 1):

`date()` takes a timestamp integer. The value you are supplying equals `Friday, January 2, 1970 8:14:01 AM`. Notice the `14:01`? That is what you are getting using `date("i:s:u",$diff);`

Go to [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) and enter `116041` into the field and you can see it for yourself.

Comment: so can i transform my number to minuts:seconds:miliseconds. As i've said that number we think is in miliseconds

Comment: The `u` format option is not supported in `date(). From php.net: Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple math.

```
// Get the minutes (60000ms per minute)
$milliseconds = 116041;
$minutes = floor(116041 / 60000);

// Find the remaining milliseconds
$milliseconds = $milliseconds % 60000;

// Continue to seconds calculation...
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `date` or `DateTime` route is more complicated. Just do some simple math...

```
$s = 116041 / 1000;
printf("%d:%02.3f", intdiv($s, 60), fmod($s, 60));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. please let me know if it of any help to you.

```
<?php
function formatMilliseconds($milliseconds) {
    $seconds = floor($milliseconds / 1000);
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);

    $seconds = $seconds % 60;
    $minutes = $minutes % 60;
    $milliseconds = $milliseconds % 1000;

    $format = '%u:%02u:%02u.%02u';
    $time = sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $milliseconds);
    return rtrim($time, '0');
}

echo formatMilliseconds(2000202123);
?>
```